# Не выводятся элементы формы через шаблонизатор thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, form, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Выводится только первый label, далее ошибка загрузки ресурса (статус 500). Ошибка появляется на атрибуте th:field.

Полный код проекта: https://github.com/ShulV/CRUD-app-1/commits/feature/DB_setting/project1

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

проверил файлы конфигурации, проверил зависимости, все нужные есть, проверил разные написания xmlns:th=... (и через www, и без www, и http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml).

IDE: IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate

просидел половину дня, так и не нашел ответа

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Person adding form</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Страница добавления человека</h2>
<form th:method="post" th:action="@{/people}" th:object="${person}">
  <label th:for="name">Введите имя:</label>
  <input type="text" th:field="*{name}" id="name"/>
  <label th:for="patronymic">Введите отчество:</label>
  <input type="text" th:field="*{patronymic}" id="patronymic"/>
  <label th:for="surname">Введите фамилию:</label>
  <input type="text" th:field="*{surname}" id="surname"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Добавить"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

requestMapping на ("/people") на контроллере

```
@GetMapping("/new")
public String newPersonPage() {
    return "people/new-person";
}

@PostMapping()
public String createPerson(@ModelAttribute("person") @Valid Person person,
                           BindingResult bindingResult) {
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors())
        return "people/new-person";

    personDAO.save(person);
    return "redirect:/people";
}
```

Comment: `public String newPersonPage(Model model) { model.addAttribute("person", new Person()); return "people/new-person"; }`

Comment: Я забыл прокинуть объект в форму. Спасибо огромное!

Answer (score 0):

Ответ дан в комментариях:

public String newPersonPage(Model model) { model.addAttribute("person", new Person()); return "people/new-person"; }

siarhei987